# how to get all the methods from a webservice _vti_bin/sites.asmx

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-server

I am facing a issue while trying to access the sites.asmx service via url for the same sharepoint version.

I have two different web applications running SP 2007 and when I m entering the "http://server1/_vti_bin_/sites.asmx" I get the below methods.

ExportWeb 
GetSiteTemplates 
GetUpdatedFormDigest 
ImportWeb

and when I am accessing the "http://server2/_vti_bin/sites.asmx" I get the below methods

CreateWeb 
DeleteWeb 
ExportSolution 
ExportWeb 
ExportWorkflowTemplate 
GetSite 
GetSiteTemplates 
GetUpdatedFormDigest 
GetUpdatedFormDigestInformation 
ImportWeb

Clearly the web methods in both the cases are not same. So I want to know how to get the missing methods in server1. Do I need to make any changes in server1 to get all methods.

FYI, My Sharepoint CSOM code internally calls this web service and I have not referenced it explicitly. When the code calls server2 my code works fine but when it calls server1 it fails.

Regards,
Agasthya

Answer (score 0):

As the server1 is running SharePoint 2007 so CreateWeb method is not available. It is available in SharePoint 2010 and 2013.

Have a look at the msdn documentations below

SharePoint 2007: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sites.sites_members(v=office.12).aspx#Public Methods

[image]

SharePoint 2010: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/websvcsites.sites_members(v=office.14).aspx#Methods

[image]

Comment: Hi Ahmad, Both my web applications are SP 2007. I was unable to figure this out due to which I had opted a workaround by using other services to complete my requirement.